# how to referencing the text inside a list item in kivymd?

Tags: python, mysql, kivy, mysql-python, kivymd

i am working on a todo app and i want to integrate it with mysql.
so far i have made adding tasks functional in it , but i am having trouble in removing tasks.
the tasks can be removed from the app window by clicking a checkbox but not from the sql database, for that i need the text inside the list item so that i can execute an sql command where it finds that text in the table and remove it.
i am a total begginer to kivymd so i need help.

some code : ( how i remove a tske in app)

```
def _remove_item(self, _):
    self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```

i need text from this same widget that is being removed

here is the KV file is someone need it(i saved it in a file named "homescreen").

```
KV = '''

<Add_Dialogbox>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        id : task
        hint_text: "Task"


    MDTextField:
        id: time
        hint_text: "Time/Description"


<Floating_Plus_Button>
    FloatLayout:
        MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: "plus"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint: {'x':.8, 'y':.14}
            on_release : app.addbutton()

<ListItemWithCheckbox>:
    LeftCheckbox:
        on_active: root.remove_item()
        
<OneLineListItemWithCheckbox>:
    LeftCheckbox:
        on_active: root.remove_item()
    
       


<Settings_tab>
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "Work Log"
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "notebook-outline"
            OneLineIconListItem:
                
                text: "Theme"
                on_release: app.opentheme()
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "theme-light-dark"
                
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "Font"
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "format-font"                                        
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "Profile"
                
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "face-profile"
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "Notifications"
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "android-messages"
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "Reset"
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "lock-reset" 
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "Log Out"
    
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "logout"



Screen:

    MDNavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'


                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Make it Happen"
                        elevation: 10
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]





                    MDBottomNavigation:
                        panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1

                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            name: 'homescreen'
                            text: 'Home'
                            icon: 'home'



                            ScrollView:
                                MDList:
                                    id: container

                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            name: 'screen 2'
                            text: 'timer'
                            icon: 'clock'

                            Screen:
                                MDLabel:
                                    id:stopwatch
                                    markup:True
                                    halign:'center'
                            
                                MDRaisedButton:
                                    text:'START'
                                    id:start_stop
                                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.25,'center_y':0.1}
                                    on_release:
                                        app.start_stop()
                            
                                MDRaisedButton:
                                    text:'RESTART'
                                    id:reset
                                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.60,'center_y':0.1} 
                                    on_release:
                                        app.reset()

                                    




                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            name: 'settings'
                            text: 'settings'
                            icon: 'cog'
                            
                            Settings_tab:
                                                                                                                              
                Floating_Plus_Button:











        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: "8dp"
                spacing: "8dp"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "<user>"
                    font_style: "Subtitle1"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                MDLabel:
                    text: "<email>"
                    size_hint_y: None
                    font_style: "Caption"
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                ScrollView:

                    MDList:
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Profile"

                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "face-profile"



                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Upload"

                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "upload"


                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: "Logout"

                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: "logout"
'''
```

The full code (it requires sql to run, and provide your own password in it in order to run)(or maybe just comment out the sql things)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivymd.uix.list import ILeftBodyTouch, TwoLineAvatarIconListItem, OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from homescreen import KV
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDThemePicker
import mysql.connector

#mysql commands

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user= "root",
    password = "Harshul@5114",
)

c = mydb.cursor()

#create database
c.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS todoapp_db")

def mysqlstuff():
    global mydb,c
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Harshul@5114",
        database="todoapp_db"
    )
    c = mydb.cursor()

mysqlstuff()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE if not exists tasks(pending varchar(100),descrip varchar(100))')





#from kivy.core.window import Window  # remove this afterwards

#Window.size = (300, 500)

# declarations

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Settings_tab(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Add_Dialogbox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Floating_Plus_Button(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ListItemWithCheckbox(TwoLineAvatarIconListItem):
    def remove_item(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self._remove_item, 1)  # delay to see the checkbox animation.

    def _remove_item(self, _):
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)

    '''Custom list item.'''
class OneLineListItemWithCheckbox(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    def remove_item(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self._remove_item, 1)  # delay to see the checkbox animation.

    def _remove_item(self, _):
        self.parent.remove_widget(self)
        print (self.parent.text)

class LeftCheckbox(ILeftBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
    pass


# app...

class ToDoApp(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    # list
    def on_start(self):
        mysqlstuff()
        c.execute('select * from tasks')
        record = c.fetchall()
        for heh in record:
            if heh[1]=='NULL':
                self.root.ids.container.add_widget(OneLineListItemWithCheckbox(text=heh[0]))
            else :
                self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                    ListItemWithCheckbox(text=heh[0],
                                         secondary_text=heh[1]))




    # add task button in dialog
    def add_task(self, obj):
        if self.dialog.content_cls.ids.time.text == '':
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItemWithCheckbox(text=self.dialog.content_cls.ids.task.text,)
                )
            values = ((self.dialog.content_cls.ids.task.text),'NULL')


        else:
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                ListItemWithCheckbox(text=self.dialog.content_cls.ids.task.text,
                                     secondary_text = self.dialog.content_cls.ids.time.text
                                     )
                )
            values = ((self.dialog.content_cls.ids.task.text), (self.dialog.content_cls.ids.time.text))
        mysqlstuff()
        sql_cmd = "INSERT INTO tasks(pending,descrip) VALUES('%s','%s')"%(values)

        c.execute(sql_cmd)
        mydb.commit()

        c.execute('select * from tasks')
        record = c.fetchall()
        for heh in record:
            print(heh)
        mydb.close()

        self.dialog.content_cls.ids.task.text = ''
        self.dialog.content_cls.ids.time.text = ''
        self.dialog.dismiss()







    # close button in dialog
    def close_dialog(self, obj):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    # open add dialog
    def addbutton(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="New Task",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Add_Dialogbox(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.close_dialog
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="OK", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color, on_release=self.add_task
                    ),

                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()





# settings tab
    def opentheme(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()








# timer tab....

    started=False
    seconds=0


    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_time, 0)

    def update_time(self, obj):
        if self.started:
            self.seconds += obj
        minutes, seconds = divmod(self.seconds, 60)
        part_seconds = seconds * 100 % 100
        self.root.ids.stopwatch.text = f'[size=45]{int(minutes):02}[/size][size=30]:[/size][size=60]{int(seconds):02}[/size][size=30].[/size][size=30]{int(part_seconds):02}[/size]'

    def start_stop(self):
        self.root.ids.start_stop.text = 'START' if self.started else 'STOP'
        self.started = not self.started
        self.root.ids.reset.disabled = True if self.started else False

    def reset(self):
        if self.started:
            self.started = False
        self.seconds = 0


ToDoApp().run()
```

Comment: Instead of posting full code try posting a [minimal executable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) one addressing the main problem. However at a first glance it seems you can use the `text` attr. of `TwoLineAvatarIconListItem` inside method `_remove_item`.

Comment: sorry for posting the entire code, i am very new here. 
i tried to print the text the list item by writing `print(self.parent.text)` but it doesnt work. what exactly do i have to write to use the `text` atrribute of `TwoLineAvatarIconListItem` ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `print(self.text)` instead of `print(self.parent.text)` ?

Comment: yes now it works thank you so much.
i have very less idea about widget referencing so i had no idea what should have been done.